# Swift 4.2 computed variable [String:Bool] does not assign value correctly

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, command-line-interface

[MacOS 10.14.1, Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2]

I'm working on creating a `getopt` style CLI argument processor whilst practising Swift.  In my design, I decided to create a computed variable, represented as a `[String:Bool]` dictionary, that can be checked to see if an option (key) is just a switch (value = true) or whether it may include parameters (value = false).  So I've written the code below, all of which is, at the moment, in my small (300 lines) `main.swift` file.

The code works correctly in a playground, but in my Swift Xcode project, whilst the dictionary's keys are correct, values are always false and inconsistent with the printed messages.

```
let options = "cwt:i:o:"
//lazy var optionIsSwitch : [String:Bool] = { (This will be moved to a class)
var optionIsSwitch : [String:Bool] = {
  var tmpOptionIsSwitch : [String:Bool] = [:]
  let optionsStrAsArray = Array(options)
  let flags = Array(options.filter { !":".contains($0) } )
  tmpOptionIsSwitch.reserveCapacity(flags.count)
  for thisOption in 0...flags.count-1 {
    var posInOptionsStr = 0
    while posInOptionsStr < optionsStrAsArray.count-1 && flags[thisOption] != optionsStrAsArray[posInOptionsStr] {
      posInOptionsStr += 1
    }
    if posInOptionsStr < optionsStrAsArray.count-1 && optionsStrAsArray[posInOptionsStr+1] == ":" {
      tmpOptionIsSwitch[String(flags[thisOption])] = false
      print("\(flags[thisOption]) is FALSE")
    } else {
      tmpOptionIsSwitch[String(flags[thisOption])] = true
      print("\(flags[thisOption]) is TRUE")
    }
  }
  return tmpOptionIsSwitch
}()
```

I've stepped through the code in my project to observe the execution sequence, and found it to be correct. As per the first image, `tmpOptionIsSwitch` returns a dictionary containing the right keys but all the values are set to false, which is inconsistent with the print statements.

[image: Xcode Project Debug with print tmpOptionIsSwitch]
As part of my debugging activities, I copied the above code into a Swift Playground where I found it gave the correct results, as per the image below.

[image: Playground Results]

Has anyone has such an issue? Is there something I've done wrong?

Comment: The *debugger view*  is sometimes wrong. Does `print(tmpOptionIsSwitch)`  print the expected result?

Comment: It's just a debug error printing. The actual value is correct.

Comment: I've updated the Xcode project debug image to include `print tmpOptionIsSwitch`, it is not correct.

Comment: @gone I can't see the difference. It the same for both command line and playground: Hello, Swift 4.2
c is TRUE
w is TRUE
t is FALSE
i is FALSE
o is FALSE
["i": false, "o": false, "c": true, "w": true, "t": false]

Comment: @Vyacheslav, no it isn't the same.  `value = false` in all cases in Xcode.  The Xcode print statements **only prove** the execution path is correct, but the assignments are *forgotten* somewhere along the way.  I'm using the print statements as a debug tool.

Comment: @gone: What I meant is that you `print(tmpOptionIsSwitch)` in your *code,* not in the debugger window.

Comment: @MartinR : You're right!  Now I know.  Apple!!!  arrrgggg.

Comment: Well, you could make that the answer then egh?

Comment: It seems that this behaviour has been observed before: https://www.google.de/search?q=xcode+debugger+shows+wrong+values+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ok, my problem is solved, and thanks to you all for helping me out.
As for the question, should I delete it?  Should it be marked as a duplicate?  What do you think?
Someone should send that link to Apple!!!